# How can I use specific Google Maps maps in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps

I'm making an app with a MapView for iOS. I would like it to add all the content of http://maps.fon.com/mapContent?lt=50.50388700000001&ln=4.469935999999928&zm=6 in my app.

This is the basic of my .h-file

```
@interface TDW_BFSecondViewController : UIViewController {

    MKMapView *mapview;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
```

I don't know what's the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using interface builder or storybuilder drag over a web view or just declare it as you have with your map view.
You can also put:

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.fon.com/mapContent?lt=50.50388700000001&ln=4.469935999999928&zm=6"]]];
```

That code shows the web view with the URL you mentioned earlier.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact copy of this page you can display a webview of this map.

But  If you want to use mapkit (google map native IOS) you should add mannualy a custom annotation per points ...

Comment: This webview is updated automatically so I can't do it manually.. If I use the webview can I integrate also the functions with buttons to get my location on the maps and to switch between Map - Satellite - Hybrid?

Answer (score 0):

You can find where you want in a my maps area of google maps and then specify that area through a UIWebview.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hmmm I didn't use UIWebViews before.. I've some troubles while trying it.